# How to set up a Regex for 000.00000001%-100.00000000%

Tags: regex

I have a RegularExpressionValidator in some .net code that should only allow 000.00000001%-100.00000000%.  I have the following, but then realized that it allows for all forms of '0'.

(^0?[0-9]?[0-9]?)(.\d{0,8})?\s?\%?$|(^100(.[0]{0,8})?\s?\%?$)

(It is intentional to allow for a potential ' %' or '%' at the end.)

I want to prevent the entry of all entries that equate to '0' such as:

0

00

000

000.0

000.00

~

.00000000

I appreciate any help provided. Thanks!

Comment: I really think you could simplify this (i might post a fresh new regex if i get some time to think about it). In the mean time, try to double up the expression and insert a mandatory "1" in the middle (something like ((..)1\.(...)|\.(...)1(...)) with "(...)" standing for your "x 0 or 1 decimals"

Comment: Not clear. Should it match 01.00? And 1.001? As a rule of thumb, whenever you have a numeric range, usually a regex is not the way to go to validate it. You will either end up with a really complex regex or even it cannot be done using a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use your regex:

```
(^0?[0-9]?[0-9]?)(.\d{0,8})?\s?\%?$|(^100(.[0]{0,8})?\s?\%?$)
```

Simplify it a bit:

```
^0?\d{0,2}(.\d{0,8})?\s?%?$|^100(.0{0,8})?\s?%?$
```

Fix the dots:

```
^0?\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,8})?\s?%?$|^100(\.0{0,8})?\s?%?$
```

Reorder it:

```
^(0?\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,8})?|100(\.0{0,8})?)\s?%?$
```

Construct the following lookahead to ensure you are not matching something *zeroish*:

```
(?!0*\.?0*\s?%?$)
```

And prepend it to the regex:

```
(?!0*\.?0*\s?%?$)^(0?\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,8})?|100(\.0{0,8})?)\s?%?$
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and it is instructive, however, it allows for '.', '.0', and empty

Comment: actually .0 to .00000000

Comment: Thanks! Perfect.  Your example is educational.